# Filter list using duplicates in another list

Tags: python, list, filter, duplicates, list-comprehension

I have two equal-length lists, `a` and `b`:

```
a = [1, 1, 2, 4, 5, 5, 5, 6, 1]
b = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h', 'i']
```

I would like to keep only those elements from `b`, which correspond to an element in `a` appearing for the first time. Expected result:

```
result = ['a', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'h']
```

One way of reaching this result:

```
result = [each for index, each in enumerate(b) if a[index] not in a[:index]]
# result will be ['a', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'h']
```

Another way, invoking Pandas:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(a=a,b=b))
result = list(df.b[~df.a.duplicated()])
# result will be ['a', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'h']
```

Is there a more efficient way of doing this for large `a` and `b`?

Comment: What values `a` and `b` contain? Lists, List with other lists, dictionaries, something else?

Comment: `b` contains lists, `a` contains dicts in my real world application. I know it isn't perfect, but it seems to be good enough to convert `b`'s elements to `str`, then Timus's solution works. I went with that option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try if this is faster:

```
firsts = {}
result = [firsts.setdefault(x, y) for x, y in zip(a, b) if x not in firsts]
```